# Tab selection in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the need of a click tab event. I am using the following code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#container-1').tabs();
        $('#start').bind('tabsselect', function(event, ui) {
            alert('tab label ' + ui.tab.text());
        });
     });
 </script>

    .....


 <div id="container-1">
     <ul>
         <li><a href="#fragment-1"><span id="start">Start</span></a></li>
         <li><a href="#fragment-2"><span id="mid">Mid </span></a></li>
           ....
         List of tabs
    </ul>
 </div>
```

Here, I need the clicked tab name, as an alert. But I am unable to execute it. I tried with jQuery 1.2.6. Should I do any other inclusion in this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you got the full list of requirements needed for the [jQuery UI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery_UI) tabs method?

The [download helper](http://ui.jquery.com/download_builder/) thing on the jQuery site is pretty helpful.